# How to check the csv file columns exist in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a *csv file* which has `30` columns.
Any idea how we can check the columns are valid with list of columns?

```
  LastName  FName   Id  DOB     Gender phonenumber mobilenumber country
```

List: ( `LastName`, `FName`,    `Id`,   `DOB`, `Gender`, `phonenumber`, `mobilenumber`, `country` )

so if any column outside the list it show error: not valid list?

Answer (score 3):

You can take the first row (column names), split it and check if your list contains the column.

```
string[] accceptedColumns = {"a", "b", "c" };
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines( path );
foreach ( var columnName in lines[0].Split( ',' ) )
{
    if ( !accceptedColumns.Contains( columnName ) )
    {
        //Invalid column
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[EpicKip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43515416/7397065) works good if you want to see if there's any column that you are not expecting (e.g. there is a column named "Z", while you are only expecting columns named "A, B and C").

Since your question is not completely clear to me I added another scenario for you. If you want to check against a predetermined set of columns (e.g. make sure that all 30 columns are present each time without deviations) you can use this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var columnInput1 = new List<string>() { "LastName", "FName", "Id", "DOB", "Gender", "phonenumber", "mobilenumber", "country" };
    bool result1 = CheckIfAllColumnsArePresent(columnInput1);
    Console.WriteLine(result1);

    var columnInput2 = new List<string>() { "LastName", "FName", "Id", "DOB", "Gender", "mobilenumber", "country" };
    bool result2 = CheckIfAllColumnsArePresent(columnInput2);
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
}

private static bool CheckIfAllColumnsArePresent(List<string> columnInput)
{
    var columnsNeeded = new List<string>() { "LastName", "FName", "Id", "DOB", "Gender", "phonenumber", "mobilenumber", "country" };

    foreach (var column in columnInput)
    {
        if (columnsNeeded.Contains(column))
            columnsNeeded.Remove(column);
    }

    return columnsNeeded.Count == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

This will check that all columns "A, B and C" are present. If you input "A, B, Z" or "A, B" it will return `false`. Only the input "A,B,C" will return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

First, we have to obtain actual columns:

```
  string fileName = @"C:\MyFile.csv";

  var columns = File
    .ReadLines(fileName)
    .SkipWhile(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .Split(new char[] { '\t', ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// .Select(item => item.Trim()); // you may want to trim column names
```

Let expected columns be represented as a list

```
 List<string> expectedColumns = new List<string>() {
    "LastName", "FName", "Id", "DOB", "Gender", "phonenumber", "mobilenumber", "country"};
```

Then we can easily check if all the columns are represented

```
 // StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase - let be nice and allow
 // phonenumber, Phonenumber, PhoneNumber
 if (expectedColumns.Except(columns, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any()) {
   // Some expected columns are not found; incorrect csv
 }
 else {
   // All expected columns are found
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var reader = new StreamReader("sourcePath");
string[] allLines = reader.ReadToEnd()
                      .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var colList = new List<string>(allLines[0].Split(','));
var isExist=colList.Exists(s => s == "Your Column Name")
```